# Access JavaBeans Property in JSP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Under a struts framework, there is a need to change the value of JavaBeans Property when the page is load. Is it possible to access the JavaBeans Property in JSP using JavaScript? The JSP code sample is below:

```
<logic:present name="obj">
   <logic:iterate id="data" name="obj">
     <tr>
        <td width="50%" valign="top" bgcolor="#C9C9C9">
           <logic:present  name="data" property="description">
               <span class="mediumBlackBold"><b>

                  <script type="text/javascript">

                  <!-- try to modify the value of description for each data -->

                  </script>
                  <jsp:getProperty name="data" property="description" />

               </b></span>
          </logic:present>
        </td>
    </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSP is server side and JS is browser side, all JS can do is just change the value show up in the HTML.

1.remove your script tag in the iterate tag because there is no need to insert so many script tag in html.

2.add a script tag in the bottom of html and use JS to get all the description value and change whatever value you want.Here is just a JQuery based sample code:

```
$(".mediumBlackBold>b").each(function(){
    var old_value = $(this).text();
    var new_value = .....
    $(this).text(new_value);
});
```